# is possible to use telnet client with react native?

Tags: react-native, telnet

Is there any way to connect to telnet server and send commands via react native ?

I Tried to test [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-telnet-client) library i facing errors because its have old dependencies and way  to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation that the site provided? https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client ,
if you have implemented it already, why not show the error ?

Comment: here the error [TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new (_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[4], "react-native-telnet-client").Telnet)()')]